# How to sort the result of Enum.GetValues without knowing the Enum itself

Tags: .net, generics, enums

I'm looking for a way to sort the result of `[Enum].GetValues(enumType)` (which is an `Array`) by the enum values names.

```
Public Enum TestEnum As Integer
    Zero = 0
    One = 1
    Two = 2
End Enum
```

I don't know the enum type at compile time, so I can't do a `Cast(Of...)` on the `Array` and use the `OrderBy` extension after that.

I only have a `Type` variable (called `enumType`) at runtime.

```
Dim enumType As Type = GetType(TestEnum)   'just for testing
Dim values As Array = [Enum].GetValues(enumType)
```

The `values` array contains {Zero, One, Two} and I'm looking for a way to get to {One, Two, Zero} (alphabetical order). Remember, you don't know about `TestEnum` at compile time, you only have the variable `enumType`.

Comment: Use Enum.GetName() to get the string you need to sort alphabetically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was hoping for a more elegant solution, but this will do:

```
Dim enumType As Type = GetType(TestEnum)
Dim names As String() = [Enum].GetNames(enumType)
Dim values As Array = names.OrderBy(Of String)(Function(x As String) x) _
                           .Select(Of Object)((Function(x As String) [Enum].Parse(enumType, x))) _
                           .ToArray
```